# Simple HTML AngularJS and Intranet server JSON Returns Nothing?

Tags: angularjs

I have a working test service on our local 2012 server which returns JSON like so:

192.168.1.11:8080/api/values

[{"ID":1,"Name":"sankar","Address":"cuttack","DOB":"1983-01-22T00:00:00"},{"ID":3,"Name":"My Test Name","Address":"My Test Address","DOB":"1980-01-01T00:00:00"}]

I'm using VS2010 and empty asp.net project (one .html page) with the following code to pull a simple list from the local server like so:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="">    
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ValuesController($scope, $http) {
            $scope.length = 0;
            $scope.data = [];

            $http.get("192.168.1.11:8080/api/values") 
       .then(
           function (result) {
               angular.copy(result.data, $scope.data);
           },
           function () {
               //handle error
           }
       );

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-ng-controller="ValuesController">

    <div class="row">
        <h2>Projects and its Tasks</h2>
        <p>Number of Projects : {{ data.length }}</p>
    </div> 

    <div data-ng-repeat="d in data">

        <p>Name : {{d.Name}}</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is Angular properly loaded? Usually, it would show {{ data.length }} if the module failed to load. Otherwise, if Angular's running and it's a problem with the request, {{ data.length }} would be blank.

Comment: Could you try to debug (F12) by adding a break-point inside function (result) to see if result.data is empty or not?

Comment: what is the output of console.log(result) in console?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the protocol to your URL. I think angular might be treating that as a relative URL without the protocol.

```
$http.get("http://192.168.1.11:8080/api/values")
```

You will also need to [enable CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) on your Web API and in AngularJS to make cross domain calls.

If you are just getting started and trying to learn how AngularJS works, you would probably be better off running the Web API under the same site that is hosting your JavaScript/HTML.